# Trying to remove list of sentences from text, only removes first character

Tags: python

I have made the following class

```
class SentenceReducer():
    def getRidOfSentences(self, line, listSentences):
        for i in listSentences:
            print(i)
            return line.replace(i, '')

    strings = 'This is a'
    def stripSentences(self, aTranscript):
        result = [self.getRidOfSentences(line, self.strings) for line in aTranScript]
        return(result)
```

It should basically eat a dataframe and then line per line check whether the relevant line conains a sentence from listSentences (1 in this example)

However when I create a new class

```
newClass = SentenceReducer()
```

And run the script with the following data

```
aTranScript = [ 'This is a test', 'This is not a test']
new_df = newClass.stripSentences(aTranScript)
```

It deletes the `'T'` in my original data. But it should replace the whole sentence (`'This is a'`). Also if I add the `print(i)` it prints `T`.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? Please fix it and try to use the standard 4-spaces to aid in readability. I see at least a couple potential logic errors. Please show us exactly what you are running, too.

Comment: best to make it a member in __init__ function.

Comment: In any event, you've defined `listSentences` as a *class level variable* thus you need to access it as such. Honestly, I see no need, and you should just pass it as an argument (which your method already does...).

Comment: Where does the NameError mentioned in the title occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `getRidOfSentences`, the variable `listSentences` has the value `'This is a'`, which is a string.

Iterating over a string gives the individual characters:

```
>>> strings = 'This is a'
>>> for x in strings:
...     print(x)
T
h
i
s

i
s

a
```

You want to put this string in a *list*, so that iterating over that list gives you the whole string, not its individual characters:

```
>>> strings = ['This is a']
>>> for x in strings:
...     print(x)
This is a
```

---

Another problem: The `return` inside the `for` loop means that the function exits at the end of the first iteration, that's why you only see `T`, but not `h`, `i`, `s` and so on.

Comment: Thanks mkrieger1, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First, `aTranscript` and `aTranScript` are not the same variable (notice the capital `s` in the latter).

Second, you should access `listSentences` with `self.listSentences` or `SentenceReducer.listSentences`.

Third, you're using `string` which isn't declared anywhere.

And last, the function `stripSentences` doesn't return anything.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I changed my code with your suggestions (see edit).  Do you have any idea why the i in my first function is printed as "T"